# Android runtime error: Library 'libmmparser.so' not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

My application runs fine when my phone isn't plugged in, but It's plugged in (so I can debug on it) the debugger fails to successfully execute the program with the following error:

> V/ExtendedExtractor(28856): Failed to open MM_PARSER_LIB, dlerror =
>   Cannot load library: load_library[1105]: Library 'libmmparser.so' not
>   found

Edit: It turns out this isn't what was causing it to fail, it was a permission problem

Edit 16/04/2013: 
I don't remember at what point in the project I had this problem (could of been when testing recording or when saving the recording), but it was one of these two:

RECORD_AUDIO

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Please tell us which permission is missing.

Comment: I don't remember at what point in the project I had this problem (could of been when testing recording or when saving the recording), but it was one of these two:

RECORD_AUDIO
or
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this isn't what was causing it to fail, it was a permission problem caused by one of these:

RECORD_AUDIO

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE